# What to change in the registry to boot Windows from a PCIe Sata controller?

Tags: windows-7, boot, ssd, windows-registry, sata

What to change in the registry to boot Windows from a PCIe Sata controller?

I have an intel mainboard that supports only 3GB Sata. I want to upgrade it to 6GB Sata with a controller like this:

http://geizhals.at/eu/msi-star-usb3-sata6-a582787.html

After installing the controller and device drivers, what do I have to change in the registry, so that I can boot from that controller, without having to reinstall Windows 7?

I have the fear that if I simply install the driver and attach the sata cable of my SSD from the internal Sata Port to the new Controller, I get an Inaccesible Boot Device bluescreen.

edit: I have not purchased the controller yet, out of the fear that I will have to reinstall Windows (will not buy it if this is the case)

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar product that I installed last year.

[image: Syba SATA III controller card]

> what do I have to change in the registry, so that I can boot from that controller, without having to reinstall Windows 7?

I had to do no registry change. There really should not be any need for that, just install the drivers.

This was to maximize a SATA III SSD into my system that had SATA II ports on the motherboard. My experience was simply to plug the card into a PCI e slot (I had a spare PCIe 2 x16) and tested it with my 7200 RPM platter drive that had the OS on it as well as my brand new SSD that I did a fresh Windows 7 install on.

I installed the drivers, shutdown the system, plugged in the drives and all went well. Bios picked up the card, the drives were recognized and no need to do a fresh install of OS.